# Is WriteFile/ReadFile on Same Handle Thread-Safe Opened Without FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED but using OVERLAPPED structure?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage

It's clear that if you open a file using `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` you need to provide the `OVERLAPPED` structure and you need to wait when returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING` and if you don't provide `hEvent` it waits on the filehandle.  Waiting on the filehandle, in this case, is not reliable because any operation that completes signals the filehandle.

Now if opened without the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` you can still provide the `OVERLAPPED` structure.   Say you provide it without an hEvent or didn't provide `OVERLAPPED` at all, what does it do internally?  If it's waiting on the file handle, it seems it would be unreliable in multi-threading applications that use the same handle in multiple threads to do file IO.

If it is multi-thread unreliable and an `hEvent` would be needed for every IO, how much overhead is involved in `CreateEvent` ?   If not, does it internally create an event and does it have the same overhead?

I need to offer in a support library ability to open a PhysicalDrive in Overlapped mode, yet still, support they Synchronous operations. A new set of functions for overlapped read/write would be created.  For the existing function calls, I was going to wait on the handle, but I think that is a problem.  So I could either create an event each time or create a one-time event that is shared and use a `Mutex` to serialize the requests, only that could kill any NCQ type performance gain, especially if not using write cache.   Understanding what Windows does internally would help a lot.

TIA!!

Comment: if you open file in synchronous mode (without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`) - when WriteFile/ReadFile return - io operation already complete. you not need any `hEvent` in overlapped (simply set it to 0 here). and you not need any wait after api retur. your question is unclear

Comment: *Understanding what Windows does internally would help a lot* - this is 100%

Comment: *you need to wait when returns ERROR_IO_PENDING* - this is not true. usually if you want **wait** - simply use synchronous io. asyncronous io - this is when we not wait, but use callback/events. use wait on event most worst choice. wait on file handle - always is wrong

Comment: I need to support synchronous io to maintain compatibility even when opened in overlapped mode.  So internally, I need to handle the wait.   You mentioned callbacks, how is that done, does it provide a user defined parameter that can be set, that would be the answer.

Comment: yes, of course callback let you set user defined parameter (context) per operation. but your current question anyway uncler for me

Comment: how do you set the callback?

Comment: `BindIoCompletionCallback` once or `CreateThreadpoolIo` once + `StartThreadpoolIo` before every io call and `CancelThreadpoolIo` if io fail.+`CloseThreadpoolIo` once

Comment: *"If it's waiting on the file handle, it seems it would be unreliable in multi-threading applications that use the same handle in multiple threads to do file IO."* This is not a problem. For synchronous I/O, threads contend for the [File object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object), which is implemented using its `Busy` flag, `Waiters` count, and `Lock` event. Thus the internal synchronization on the File object's `Event` is safe.

Comment: Thanks, so that suggests to me that overlapped io could not be duplicated by using multiple threads requesting the IO over a handle opened in synchronous mode (that is opened without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`) ?

Comment: It also seems that maybe opening 2 handles would be the way to go, one in overlapped mode and one in sync mode, old interface uses sync, optional overlapped uses that one.   Any problem doing that?

Comment: 2 handles great, except for locking, have to use the locked handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.

Signalling an event or the file handle is for the benefit of user-mode code waiting for operations.  The driver internally is using a completely different synchronization scheme -- the IRP (I/O request packet).  Multiple operations will not accidentally complete the wrong request as you seem to worry about.

(As a matter of fact, there is no synchronous I/O model behind the scenes.  All I/O is done using IRPs and continuation-passing-style.  Synchronous operations in user mode are emulated by performing an async kernel I/O and marking the current thread non-runnable pending that operation.  Note that it is pended on the operation, not the event object or file object.)

Comment: The concern is if you call `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` and internally waits on the file handle then it could be signaled when another io operation in another thread completed.  So they all complete but not sure which one completed.  On the other hand, if it is safe, then does that mean using multiple threads to write to a handle is serialized and you don't have a chance to leverage things like NCQ when writing to the physical drive.  Can overlapped issue multiple requests and potentially leverage NCQ?  With traditional drives, cache and arm movement, SSD type maybe someday do them all at once.

Comment: @user3161924: Multiple threads writing to a file without an explicit offset have to be serialized, or else the data could end up interleaved.  But write cache comes to the rescue and allows those writes to complete almost instantly.  NCQ can certainly kick in when flushing to disk, cache enables NCQ no matter what API you use.  And operations using the OVERLAPPED structure (with or without FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED) can fully run in parallel, with a few exceptions for writing compressed files, or those that have to update filesystem metadata under lock (but only the metadata updates are serial).