# Win32 ReadFile function blocks on unrelated threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to start a number of (external) processes and capture their output. Since my commandlines exceed 8191 characters, I can not make use of `popen`/`pclose`, but instead I am using the `CreateProcess` Win32 API functionality, as described in [this Win32 learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ProcThread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

Now, my rough outline looks like so:

1. spawn N threads (C++ `<thread>`'s)
2. every thread tries to grab a piece of work, and if it has one, starts the external process with the parameters as given
3. `WaitForSingleObject` until the external process is done
4. `ReadFile` the output pipe until it is empty
5. close all handles
6. goto 2), check if more work needs doing.

I am observing the following: All threads start their external process, but for some reason, **all block in `ReadFile` until every thread has reached `ReadFile`**!
I would understand a deadlock if I was leaving some handles open that should be closed, etc., but I do not understand why and how this could happen.
Again, if `ReadFile` would block if I request too many bytes, I would understand a deadlock, but why is it unblocking when every thread reaches `ReadFile`?

To demonstrate this issue, I have created an (almost) minimal working example.
It has two components, one mimics the external process (`sleepHelper.cpp`) and the other one spawns a variable number of threads: One always takes `5 seconds` to run, while all additional threads take `500ms`.

This allows us to observe the behavior:

```
.\MinimalExample.exe 3
Using thread count = 3
Thead 3: Waiting for object took 525ms.
Thead 2: Waiting for object took 525ms.
Thead 3: Reading output took 4489ms.
Thead 2: Reading output took 4489ms.
Thead 3: Executing process took 5022ms.
Thread 3 is exiting.
Thead 2: Executing process took 5022ms.
Thread 2 is exiting.
Thead 1: Waiting for object took 5015ms.
Thead 1: Reading output took 0ms.
Thead 1: Executing process took 5023ms.
Thread 1 is exiting.
Total runtime was 5025ms.
```

My questions are:

1. Why does `ReadFile` block here?
2. Why does it return when all threads have reached this point?

For your convenience, you can [find the MWE here](https://github.com/blizzard4591/ReadFileMWE).

SleepHelper (needs to be compiled to `sleepHelper.exe`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Expected an argument." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::string const arg(argv[1]);
    auto const time = std::stoull(arg);

    std::cout << "Going to sleep for " << time << " ms." << std::endl;

    auto const sleepStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    const std::chrono::duration<std::size_t, std::milli> duration(time);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
    auto const sleepEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto const timeSlept = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(sleepEnd - sleepStart).count();
    std::cout << "Slept for " << timeSlept << "us." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The main code:

```
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>

static std::mutex mutex;

void PrintMessageLocked(std::string const& s) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

void PrintTimeLocked(char const* what, std::size_t const& threadId, std::size_t const& usTaken) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << "Thead " << threadId << ": " << what << " took " << usTaken << "ms." << std::endl;
}

std::tuple<int, std::string> ExecuteProcessAndCaptureOutput(std::string command, std::string workingDirectory, std::size_t const& myThreadId) {
    /*
        Why this whole mumbu-jumbo instead of a simple popen/pclose()?
        Because the maximum length of command line arguments is 8191 characters on Windows, but almost all invocations are longer than that.
    */
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
    DWORD const outputBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, outputBufferSize)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create STDOUT pipe for child process, last error = " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set handle information for child process, last error = " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }

    STARTUPINFOA startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));

    startupInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    startupInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcessA(NULL, command.data(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, workingDirectory.data(), &startupInfo, &processInformation);
    if (!bSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create process, last error = " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }

    // Close unnecessary pipes
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);

    // Wait until child process exits.
    auto const waitStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    DWORD const timeoutInMs = 30000; // Can be INFINITE
    auto const waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, timeoutInMs);
    if (waitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        std::cerr << "Internal Error: Execution took longer than " << timeoutInMs << "ms, abandoning!" << std::endl;

        std::cerr << "Command was: '" << command << "'" << std::endl;
        auto const terminationResult = TerminateProcess(processInformation.hProcess, -1);
        if (terminationResult == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Internal Error: Failed to terminate sub-process :(" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    auto const waitEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto const waitTimeTaken = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(waitEnd - waitStart).count();
    PrintTimeLocked("Waiting for object", myThreadId, waitTimeTaken);

    DWORD exitCode = 0;
    bSuccess = GetExitCodeProcess(processInformation.hProcess, &exitCode);
    if (bSuccess == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Internal Error: Failed to get exit code from process!" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
    else if (exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE) {
        std::cerr << "Internal Error: Failed to get exit code from process, it is still running!" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);

    // Collect output from process
    auto const outputStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    constexpr DWORD BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    std::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> buffer;
    std::string resultString;
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    try {
        do {
            bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buffer.data(), BUFFER_SIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
            if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;
            resultString.append(buffer.data(), dwRead);
        } while (true);
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Internal Error: Encountered an exception while reading process output!" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
    auto const outputEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto const outputTimeTaken = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(outputEnd - outputStart).count();
    PrintTimeLocked("Reading output", myThreadId, outputTimeTaken);

    // And close the handle to reading STDOUT
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);

    return std::make_tuple(static_cast<int>(exitCode), resultString);
}



void ThreadFunction(std::vector<std::size_t> const& times, std::size_t const myThreadId) {
    std::size_t const maxTimes = times.size();
    static std::atomic<std::size_t> workCounter = 0;
    while (true) {
        std::size_t const currentTimeIndex = workCounter++;
        if (currentTimeIndex >= maxTimes) {
            break;
        }
        auto const& myTime = times.at(currentTimeIndex);

        auto const procStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto const [res, output] = ExecuteProcessAndCaptureOutput(".\\sleepHelper.exe " + std::to_string(myTime), std::filesystem::current_path().string(), myThreadId);
        auto const procEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto const procTimeTaken = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(procEnd - procStart).count();
        PrintTimeLocked("Executing process", myThreadId, procTimeTaken);
    }

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        std::cout << "Thread " << myThreadId << " is exiting." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::size_t threadCount = 3;
    if (argc > 1) {
        threadCount = std::stoull(argv[1]);
    }
    if (threadCount < 1 || threadCount > 64) {
        std::cerr << "Thread count out of bounds. Use 1 <= thread count <= 64." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Using thread count = " << threadCount << std::endl;



    std::vector<std::size_t> times = {
        5000,
    };
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < threadCount; ++i) {
        times.push_back(500);
    }

    auto timeStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(&ThreadFunction, times, i + 1);
    }
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    auto timeEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Total runtime was " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeEnd - timeStart).count() << "ms." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- I am aware I can peek the pipe first and only read the bytes available, but since the learn article only uses ReadFile and *it works when all threads reach the point*, I am very curious about why this is as it is.
- Technically, all threads execute one successful read using `ReadFile`, read 49 Bytes and then hang and finally return with zero Bytes read.

Comment: It would be useful if you provide minimal reproducible example. For me personally I can't answer you straight away with only the description given. But maybe someone else can?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Please take a look at the MWE linked in my question: https://github.com/blizzard4591/ReadFileMWE

Comment: But still include some snippet in the question itself too. I mean like embed the code itself in the question body.

Comment: `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you still need to do something with the last parameter of ReadFile the overlapped bit (FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile that part specifically seems to address asynchronous behavior

Comment: Some more info may be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084081/is-writefile-readfile-on-same-handle-thread-safe-opened-without-file-flag-overla

Comment: @Raffallo But I do not want asynchronous reads! The process writing to this pipe has already exited, I just want to consume what is there. The question is WHY is it blocking and every more so, WHY is it UNBLOCKING itself?

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD you should post the code in the question anyway, even if you've provided a github link.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Done. I did not want to pollute the question with a wall of code, but if you think this is better.

Comment: Why not use message queue instead - why do you use pipe specifically? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagea with the process thread handle. And in the process you peek for messages from the default thread.

Comment: Never mind - how about try to set HANDLE_FLAG_PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE on the handle passed to the child process in case some-how it's closed (because it's stdout I don't know).

Comment: @HansPassant The sub-processes complete at different times, n-1 do so after 500ms and one after 5000ms - therefore, flushing/program completion also does not happen for all at the same time?!

Comment: On a side note: `resultString += buffer.data();` is wrong as the buffer is not null terminated.  `ReadFile()` tells you how many bytes it read, so use `dwRead` to help you add the bytes to the string, eg: `resultString.append(buffer.data(), dwRead);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not that your threads just "reach" the ReadFile call, but that the last of the child processes exits.

IMO, this is what happens: while you prevent inheriting the read handle of the pipe, the write handle is inherited (since the child should write to it) - unfortunately the last running child inherited all previous write handles, keeping them open and blocking ReadFile until it exits.

To solve it, we would need a way to selectively inherit handles: each child should only know its "own" pipe end.

There's a rather old question here, that should be related:
[Select which handles are inherited by child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344887/select-which-handles-are-inherited-by-child-process) This question links to an even older [article by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873). For simplicity I'm refering to it.

For demonstration purposes you may include the `CreateProcessWithExplicitHandles` function from the article and replace your call to CreateProcessA by:

```
 BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcessWithExplicitHandles(NULL, command.data(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, workingDirectory.data(), &startupInfo, &processInformation,
    1, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
```

The last two parameters specify that there is a single handle (using an array is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)) to be inherited - which is the thread-local pipe write handle.

The minimal example now works as intended.

For reference and archiving purposes I'll include the source of `CreateProcessWithExplicitHandles`:

```
BOOL CreateProcessWithExplicitHandles(
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  __inout_opt  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  __in         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  __in         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  __in_opt     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  __in         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  __out        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation,
    // here is the new stuff
  __in         DWORD cHandlesToInherit,
  __in_ecount(cHandlesToInherit) HANDLE *rgHandlesToInherit)
{
 BOOL fSuccess;
 BOOL fInitialized = FALSE;
 SIZE_T size = 0;
 LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST lpAttributeList = NULL;
 fSuccess = cHandlesToInherit < 0xFFFFFFFF / sizeof(HANDLE) &&
            lpStartupInfo->cb == sizeof(*lpStartupInfo);
 if (!fSuccess) {
  SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
 }
 if (fSuccess) {
  fSuccess = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &size) ||
             GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
 }
 if (fSuccess) {
  lpAttributeList = reinterpret_cast<LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST>
                                (HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size));
  fSuccess = lpAttributeList != NULL;
 }
 if (fSuccess) {
  fSuccess = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(lpAttributeList,
                    1, 0, &size);
 }
 if (fSuccess) {
  fInitialized = TRUE;
  fSuccess = UpdateProcThreadAttribute(lpAttributeList,
                    0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST,
                    rgHandlesToInherit,
                    cHandlesToInherit * sizeof(HANDLE), NULL, NULL);
 }
 if (fSuccess) {
  STARTUPINFOEX info;
  ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
  info.StartupInfo = *lpStartupInfo;
  info.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(info);
  info.lpAttributeList = lpAttributeList;
  fSuccess = CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,
                           lpCommandLine,
                           lpProcessAttributes,
                           lpThreadAttributes,
                           bInheritHandles,
                           dwCreationFlags | EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,
                           lpEnvironment,
                           lpCurrentDirectory,
                           &info.StartupInfo,
                           lpProcessInformation);
 }
 if (fInitialized) DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(lpAttributeList);
 if (lpAttributeList) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, lpAttributeList);
 return fSuccess;
}
```

Comment: I just did not realize handles were inherited quite like this. Thank you for pointing this out, the solution works as expected!